# How to Copy files from one Ubuntu server to another? (MYSQL Database for website migration)

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, migration, website, copy

I'm very new to Ubuntu and my first task is to copy one website with a MySQL database to another server. Both servers are virtual machines and in the same environment. I have both the IP addresses and login credentials.

I can sign in remotely from my Windows computer to both machines of course (old server has Ubuntu 10.10 , new server has Ubuntu 12.04).

Now I need to know if i can either copy directly from one Ubuntu server to another or first to my computer and then to the other Ubuntu server.

Or are there maybe many solutions?

Comment: In posting my answer, I find I need a bit more information on your setup. Firstly there's multiple dialects of SQL - I've covered mysql (and I believe its derivatives) and postgres. This would be very different for other databases. Likewise configuration of webservers varies wildly, especially taking into account scripting languages. I've posted a generic answer but if you could add this in, I can improve my answer further.

Comment: This is non trivial and requires way more information than you have provided. YOu should take a look at http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/migrating-a-linux-server-from-the-command-line-stage-1 it and it's associated scripts may help you.

Comment: i don't know why you guys downvote this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rsync for this, 
**Example,**

we are assuming that you have ssh access to both server's, old.com is for old one,
and the uname is the same on both servers
and the file tree to copy is /var/somedir
login to the new server,

```
rsync -av user@old.com:/var/somedir/* /var/somedir/
```

It will login to old.com and prompt for authentication, then build a file list and copy the content to the target on the current server.

I hope you understand this...
Thank you

Comment: rsync probably is a better choice for file transfers than sftp or scp as I suggested in my answer - especially if you're moving large files.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, one dosen't simply walk into mordor, I mean copy databases. You need to do this *right*. You'll want to make sure there's no ongoing writes, then make sure everything is copied in a ACID manner. You *could* shut down the database, move it, then get hit with the realisation things went horribly wrong cause they're different versions...

Luckily mysql comes with a tool to do this called [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html) - and there's [a question on SO on using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-mysql-dump-file) with lots of syntax examples - It should be something like `mysql -u<user> -p < db_backup.dump`. I would also recommend checking the versions since you may need to run an [upgrade script](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.6/en/restore-upgrade.html) between versions. Move the DUMP file, don't copy the database. Run the dump, run the upgrade script, test. As you can tell, Mysql has good resources on it, so read up and make sure you know what you're doing.

If you're using postgres, there's also [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html) (which has an oh so elegant syntax). And its [file level backup documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-file.html) is true anywhere - since shutting down a server is the surest way to not have writes while you're backing up, mucking up consistancy.

To move the dump file while there's quite a few methods [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) is probably the ideal combination of speed and security. You can transfer files computer to computer with [pscp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pscp) or download them to your windows system, then reupload them with [cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/). Since you already have SSH, this should be the simplest way to do this.

Web server configuration, and files (IE, the effective contents of /etc/ and /var/www) should be alright to copy, since they arn't constantly being changed.

Comment: Called ***mysqldump***. Remember to extract all, including stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks, corrected that. I guess I remembered the name incorrectly, and had googled for sqldump op pull up the documentation

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scp` or `rsync` for sending files/directories between your Ubuntu servers directly.

e.g.:

```
scp -r /local_dir/path user@otherhost:/remote_dir/path
```

Databases can be migrated by using the backup/dump and restore functionality that's typically provided by your DB server software (MySQL, Postegres, etc.). The exact process depends on your database server.